# Variable not updating in onCreateOptionsMenu method, android Java

Tags: android, variables, oncreateoptionsmenu

I have an integer variable that is not being updated when a share intent is activated. What am I missing? Thanks.

Integer i1 is declared in the class:

```
private int i1;
```

Here is the onCreateOptionsMenu method

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.pun, menu);
        star = menu.findItem(R.id.action_favoritestar);
        init();

        MenuItem shareItem = (MenuItem) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_share);

        shareAction = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(shareItem);

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "\"" + mLines.get(i1));

        shareAction.setShareIntent(intent);

        return true;
    }
```

The variable is modified when a button is pressed:

```
final Button btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.next);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                star.setIcon(R.drawable.starblank);

            Random r = new Random();
            i1 = r.nextInt(20 - 1) + 1;

            textView.setText(mLines.get(i1));

           }
    });
```

Comment: It is getting updated but since the menu is created only once its beingused only once. Store the intent instance in a field variable and update the extra directly on click.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to find a solution using  'Activity.invalidateOptionsMenu()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. The share options menu was not being updated more than once. I called `invalidateOptionsMenu()` after each button press.